# Boost converter shorts out the power supply under load

Tags: inductor, boost, tl494

I'm building a DC-DC step-up (boost) converter using TL494. The schematic is attached

- Input voltage: 9V
- The resistive divider at the output sets the output voltage to about 14V
- Desired output current: 3-4A
- The L1 inductor is wound on an iron powder core, the details are below
- C1, R1, R2 set the oscillation frequency to 200kHz
- C2 and R3 provide soft start functionality

My issue is that after the output current exceeds a certain value (I'll call it *threshold current*), the circuit shorts out the power supply (making it go into CC mode). The supply voltage drops to about 2-3V, Q1 stays open. The short doesn't go away even if I remove the load.

Also, as I get close to the threshold current, the input current gets close to the 3A limit of my supply (about 2.9A) no matter the input voltage - even if it is 13V, the input current is still 2.9A. The power supply doesn't go into constant current mode.

Here are some details about L1:
**Core:** yellow-white iron powder ring from an ATX power supply output filter, dimensions: 22mm outer diameter, 13mm inner diameter, 9mm height.
**Test 1:** 24 turns of wire, about 47uH inductance, 2.2A threshold current
**Test 2:** 13 turns of wire, about 10uH inductance, 2A threshold current

I thought that this issue could have something to do with inductor saturation, but reducing the number of turns is supposed to increase the saturation current (unfortunately I don't have the equipment to measure it). Here the effect seems to be the opposite. Maybe it has something to do with the increased ripple current?

Any extra information or help would be appreciated.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: How is that 9V/3A power supply supposed to supply enough power to boost up to 4A @14V?

Comment: what an unfortunate power supply.  did you reduce resistance anywhere while you were reducing the number of turns?

Comment: What does the laws of thermodynamics say about this?

Comment: You aren't limiting the duty cycle, which means that your TL494 will turn the FET on permanently and short out the supply voltage.

Comment: Yellow/white powdered iron core is probably no good for 200kHz inductor. It was probably used for filtering where the lossiness was an advantage. Make your inductor from the ferrite core of the transformer. As the others have mentioned, you can't get more power out than what you put in.

Comment: I totally understand that I can't get more power than I put in, but I'm not trying to draw 4A now. I'm trying to go over the 2.2A threshold, so 31W of power. As I also mentioned, I was testing it with an increased supply voltage, about 13-13.5V, which is about 40W at 3A.

Comment: @Jonathan S. TL494 has a 3% minimum deadtime (when pin 4 is grounded), so 97% duty cycle is the maximum.

Comment: @Kartman Do I need an EE/EI core? Is an air gap necessary?

Comment: @Abel Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Which resistance? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: You don’t necessarily need a EI core but you need a core made out of suitable material. Gap/no gap? You’re making inductors from unknown cores, so expect to fiddle it.

Comment: 97% on-time is close enough to a short that it doesn't make a difference. You could use the pulse-steering flip-flop to limit the duty cycle to roughly 50%, which is a much more sane value for your circuit (it just means the output voltage can't go higher than 2x the input voltage). Alternatively, connect a voltage divider to the dead-time control pin to get the same effect. Of course you still need a 9V power supply that can put out more current.

Comment: @Kartman I wound about 12 turns of wire on an EE16 core with a very small air gap (I made it with a sheet of thin paper). The inductance is about 20uH, the converter works much better, it can handle the load and the efficiency is a lot higher. Thank you for your help

Comment: @JonathanS. I tried adding a resistor across C2 to limit the duty cycle. The circuit works fine both with and without this addition, but I'll keep your advice in mind if I run into similar problems later down the road. Thank you.